# Can Firestore rules have exceptions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to allow authenticated read/write to match `/users/{userid}/{document=**}`, i.e. all documents under `/users/userid`, *except* for `/users/{userid}/account-info/{document=**}` which is the privileged area for admins only. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a wildcard like `/users/{userid}/{document=**}` to provide access to a hierarchy of documents, it's not possible to deny access to one of those documents with another rule.  With security rules, if **any** rule allows access to a document, then that access is permanent and can't be overridden.  I suggest reading the documentation on [overlapping match statements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements).

If you want to disallow access to one subcollection called "account-info", then you will instead have to write your rules to only allow access to each of the other subcollections, and omit "account-info" altogether.

You might also want to consider grouping the subcollections into "public" and "private" groups so it's easier to apply different rules.  For example:

```
/users-public/{userid}/{document=**}
/users-private/{userid}/{document=**}
```

Then write rules to protect them differently based on their top-level collection.